# iphone - exposing events (notifications) when creating a customized view

Tags: iphone, events, uiview, notifications

I am creating a view class that inherits from UIView. I want to expose some events (like UIButton has: Touch Down, Touch Up Inside, Touch Up Outside, etc.). I found online how to fire up an event, but how do I expose it so that the user can assign an IBAction to it (e.g. so that it is shown in the interface builder like it does for UIButton)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Declare a method in your UIView's header file and mark its return type as IBAction (this is merely a marker for a void return type that IB uses to identify wire-able actions/methods).

```
- (IBAction)userCausedViewEvent;
```

Now when you crate a UIView and assign its class type to your UIView subtype in Interface Builder, `userCausedViewEvent` should be a selectable/wire-able event method.

Comment: I meant it the other way around - IBAction indicates a method to be called when some event fires. I want to create the event itself.